# Xbox One Controller triggers function weird after 2 minutes of being turned on

Tags: pc, controllers

I'm using an Xbox One controller with my PC.

The controller functions perfectly for the first 2 minutes, both <kbd>RT</kbd> and <kbd>LT</kbd> changes its values from 0 to 255 properly  but after some time, the triggers set it's initial value at ~120 (half of 255).

So basically in game it acts like the button is half-pressed. They still work and change state from ~120 to 255 but most games recognize the trigger as pressed if value =/ 0 so it becomes unplayable.

When plugging controller out and back in - triggers works fine for another 2 minutes.

Any ideas?

That could be a solution to calibrate gamepad after issue with joy.cpl but XInput ignores joy.cpl calibration (guess calibration uses directinput).

I have no opportunity to send it back to MS or to update controller with
Xbox.

[image: Xbox controller button mapping]